# Как можно подключиться к сокетам через Vue.js 3 версии?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

сегодня начал изучать Vue.js, когда получил теорию сразу же решил попрактиковаться, написать мини чат, так как имею опыт работы с реактом около полугода могу понять что к чему. Написал я вообщем шаблон и пытаюсь сделать подключение к бэкенду через socket.io-client, в итоге ничего не получается. Бэкенд свой на Node.js, пробовал так-же через другого клиента подключиться и всё было окей. Решил погуглить, увидел что есть одно решение, это [vue-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io), но проблема в том, что данный пакет подходит лишь для второй версии, поэтому я не знаю что делать. Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, здесь посмотреть:

- https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/282
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-3-socket.io